# Is it possible to apply a HTML5/CSS/jQuery GUI onto an embedded Flash video?

Tags: jquery, flash, html, video

I would like to take a **Flash** video that is hosted on another site (like Youtube) and embed it into my own site with a custom designed **HTML5** / **CSS** / **jQuery** GUI for player controls.

**Is this possible?**

or

**Would I have to create the new player GUI in Flash?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For YouTube, there is the [chromeless player](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player), it has an initial play button and a YouTube logo, but apart from that, you can make your own user interface and control the video playback from JavaScript.

Comment: so does Chromeless player work only for Youtube? could it work for sites like Vimeo, Metacafe, Viddler?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Youtube makes its videos inaccessible to all but the Youtube player. You'd have to rip the video, rehost it in an unprotected format or in a format you can use, and then play it through your own player. The player could then interact pretty simply with the embedding site via the ordinary AS3-Javascript interface. Tutorials on how to do this are [plentiful](http://simplistika.com/as3-javascript-communication/) on the Internet.

Comment: But I suppose it would be illegal to rip videos hosted on other sites and host them on my own site.

Answer (score 1):

depends on the parcituclar case [jw player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) does just that for youtube.

Comment: Can JW Player be used for videos from sites like Metacafe, Dailymotion, Viddler, Vimeo, Blip.tv, etc? Or does one need to have access to those sites' APIs?